# Is this 110v 1hp motor reversible by swapping leads?

Tags: powertools, electric-motor

When wired for 115v, is this motor reversible by swapping leads?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv7zk.jpg

Comment: never mind. I found an online pdf of the manual for this particular motor, which gives instructions for reversing (swap red leads)

Comment: http://vintagemachinery.org/pubs/detail.aspx?id=2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

1. tag the red lead on T4 with electrical tape
2. remove the red leads from T4 and 3, leaving the black lead connected to 3
3. connect the tagged red lead to 3
4. connect the untagged red lead to T4

(This is how you implement the "swap the red leads" procedure mentioned briefly on the nameplate.)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of swap the power cord leads, but see now it requires swapping the internal red leads